# error with conversion in asp mvc c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the following lines of code:

```
NavItemsDataContext navDB = new NavItemsDataContext();
Nav n = navDB.Navs.Select(row => row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"]));
```

I am trying to access any row in my database that has an ID that matches my hidden "ID" on my form.

> Error  23  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'MvcApplication1.Models.Nav'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: select is misleading, it doesn't do a select as in a sql select statement - use .Find(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"]) to do a select on a primary key

Answer (score 2):

You want to actually obtain the object, this won't happen until you use the FirstOrDefault like below;

```
navDB.Navs.FirstOrDefault(row => row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"]));
```

May be worth also reading up on Linq's deferred loading

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, this change results in error Error 22 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<bool>' to 'MvcApplication1.Models.Nav'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
Nav n = navDB.Navs.Where(row => 
                 row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"])).FirstorDefault();
```

**Edit:** After having conversation with you (see comments) i have came to this solution

```
Nav n = navDB.Navs.Where(row => 
        {
            int i = 0;

            if (int.TryParse(Request.Form["ID"].ToString(), out i))
            {
                if(row.ID == i)
                 return true;
            }

            return false;
        }).FirstorDefault();
```

Comment: This lets me build without any errors, but when I get to this part of the site it gives me: Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: @KarlHumphries: Check what is coming in `Request.Form["ID"]`

Comment: This is exactly what I need to do, but I'm new to this and don'y know how to check if Request.Form["ID"] is what it should be. Thanks for your help so far

Comment: @KarlHumphries: Put a debug point just before this line. When that debug point is hit select `Request.Form["ID"]` and press Shift + F9. It will open quickwatch. There you can see what is there in it.

Comment: If i'm in the right place, i extend Request, then Form, it shows System.Web.HttpValueCollection ID=1&ID=2&ID=3 etc

Comment: This underline the word row on the 1st line and says: A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree

Comment: Put `Request.Form["ID"].ToString()` instead of `Request.Form["ID"]`

Comment: @KarlHumphries: After i there should be 2 closing brackets.

Comment: The 2 brackets has fixed that one, but row on the top line still reports the same problem.  Thank you for your patience

Comment: Do you have teamviewer software installed. Its a freeware through which i can see your desktop and debug your code.

Comment: No I don't have that, will look into it

Answer (score 0):

```
Nav n = navDB.Navs.Where(row => row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"])).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks, This lets me build without any errors, but when I get to this part of the site it gives me: Exception Details: System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the LINQ extension method `Select` returns a `IQueryable` of whatever type you map.

You actually want a single element, by its ID. If it is not possible for it to not exist, you should use `Single`. Otherwise, you should use `SingleOrDefault`.

Using `Single` (**throws** if not found):

```
Nav nav = navDB.Navs.Single(row => row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"])).
```

Using `SingleOrDefault` (returns `null` if not found):

```
Nav nav = navDB.Navs.SingleOrDefault(row => row.ID == Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["ID"])).
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks, this is the code I started with, I had the same problem, it implies I am trying to convert bool to int (I dont think I am)

Comment: Have you used the debugger? What value does Request.Form["ID"] have? What type is Nav.ID?